# Loading selected CSV columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, csv, mariadb

I'm trying to import selected columns from a CSV to the DB using:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'local/path/to/file.csv' 
INTO TABLE product 
(ItemName,ItemShortDescription,RetailPrice,Brand,Category,@PRICE_1,@PRICE_2,@PRICE_3,Weight,Length,Width,Height) 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' 
ESCAPED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

.. so skipping the 3 columns from the CSV (PRICE_1,PRICE_2,PRICE_3)

`product` table:

```
CREATE TABLE `product` (
  `pid` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ItemName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ItemShortDescription` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `RetailPrice` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Brand` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Category` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Weight` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Length` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Width` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Height` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11387 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

.. but it results in an error.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mysql documentation on [load data](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) says, the field list comes **after** the field/line delimiters.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'local/path/to/file.csv' 
INTO TABLE product  
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' 
ESCAPED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(ItemName,ItemShortDescription,RetailPrice,Brand,Category,@PRICE_1,@PRICE_2,@PRICE_3,Weight,Length,Width,Height)
```

Comment: Darn, that was it! Thanks! :)